# How to change the linux user (oracle/grid) that create/zip/send files through a Oracle 11g procedure

Tags: java, linux, database, oracle, oracle11g

We did an export of a Oracle 11g database and then an import of this database on another machine. One database package create txt files, concat txt files using "cat" and ">>" command, also zip some txt files and send files trough ssh (scp command) to a remote machine.

In the second machine, with the cloned database, the files are created, zipped and sent by linux user "grid", when I run the package manually on SQL Developer or TOAD, but on the original database the files are created, zipped and sent by linux user "oracle".

Where can I control this?
I want to create, zip and send the files with user "oracle" because it doesn't work whit user grid. I get permission denied trying to use cat or scp on the following commands:

```
host_command('cd '||trim(path_oracle_folder)||';/usr/bin/zip '||trim(filename_zip)||' '||trim(filename_txt));

host_command(p_command => 'cd '||trim(path_oracle_folder)||';/usr/bin/scp -p '||trim(filename_zip)||' '||trim(destination_user)||'@'||trim(destination_user_host)||':'||trim(destination_user_folder)||');
```

Comment: These are probably the Oracle instance owner IDs on the respective machines. You cannot change the owner ID after installing Oracle; consider using `sudo` if you need to run commands as a specific user.

Comment: Where can I check the Oracle instance owner IDs on the respective machine? I would like to keep the same package/procedure and try to do something at Linux machine level.

Comment: This would be the ID that runs Oracle processes, so something like this: `ps -ef | grep smon`. As I said, this cannot be changed without reinstalling Oracle.

Comment: I see user grid on line "asm_smon_+ASM" and user oracle on line "ora_smon_INSTANCENAME" on both machines. I agree this is an issue about oracle installation. I would like to prove that.